# Groupoid structure of a kernel pair

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, groupoids

I would have probably very short and simple question. In https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/%C4%8Cech+nerve there is a statement

> Čech nerve of a morphism $f$ is the internal nerve of the internal groupoid corresponding to the kernel pair of this morphism.

What is actual multiplication in this groupoid? Or more generally, how to find all faces and degeneracies of this simplicial object? I tried to see all these maps only from morphisms which create limiting cones of $k$-folded pullbacks, but I failed to see all of them. If this is the right way how to obtain all faces and degeneracies I would ask for a brief explanation of how to  obtain face map corresponding to the groupoid multiplication in question.

Comment: Calling it a groupoid is a bit grandiose – unless you are working in a higher category, it's merely an equivalence relation. The groupoid composition is simply the witness of transitivity: if we think of elements of the kernel pair as pairs $(x_0, x_1)$, then the composable pairs are of the form $((x_0, x_1), (x_1, x_2))$ and the composite is $(x_0, x_2)$.

Comment: Thanks @ZhenLin. I know the composition law you mentioned, but where does it come from? Concretely, there are three face maps between 2. and 1. degrees. Both projections (on the left and right component of $((x_0, x_1), (x_1, x_2))$ are completely defined by morphisms which we get from pullback construction. The last map which can be interpreted as a composition must be given by hand? And is the situation different, when we do Čech nerves in higher category theory? I would guess that there is entire simplicial structure determined by the Kan extension. This treatment is too abstract however.

Comment: I don't know what answer you are looking for. The map is not "given by hand" in the sense that it is natural and always present – _if_ you have a kernel pair. But if all you have is a parallel pair, or even a reflexive pair, then you can't construct it.

Comment: Thank you @ZhenLin again for your response. My goal is to undestand what is the Čech nerve construction in _any_ category admitting pullbacks. Notably, also in categories which do not allow us to speak about individual elements (like categories which are not concrete categories https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/concrete+category ). I would be happy if I get some category theory friendly description of this multiplication, by which I mean a description solely based on what we have at disposal in any category.

Comment: One possible way is to unwind the Kan extension definition of  the Čech nerve into more explicit form and obtain face and degeneracy maps out of it. But currently I do not know how to attack this issue.

Comment: You can think in terms of generalised elements via the Yoneda embedding for this purpose. Or you can treat it as a kind of abbreviation for an otherwise very long-winded specification for a morphism between objects constructed by iterated pullbacks. I advise you to think about how things would work in $\textbf{Set}$ and then generalise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127631/discussion-between-nary-and-zhen-lin).